# WebRTC dataChannel is never open

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've created a demo on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/YeGwWo?editors=1010) it work it's based on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0 article.

I have two buttons `first` is executed to listen for (like the `join` event in the article) and the second is to create connect (like create following ready event).
the main function look like this:

```
function createPeerConnection(isInitiator, config) {
  console.log('Creating Peer connection as initiator?', isInitiator, 'config:',
              config);
  peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

  // send any ice candidates to the other peer
  peerConn.onicecandidate = function(event) {
    console.log('icecandidate event:', event);
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({
        type: 'candidate',
        label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
        id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
        candidate: event.candidate.candidate
      });
    } else {
      console.log('End of candidates.');
    }
  };

  if (isInitiator) {
    console.log('Creating Data Channel');
    dataChannel = peerConn.createDataChannel('photos');
    onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);

    console.log('Creating an offer');
    peerConn.createOffer(onLocalSessionCreated, logError);
  } else {
    peerConn.ondatachannel = function(event) {
      console.log('ondatachannel:', event.channel);
      dataChannel = event.channel;
      onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);
    };
  }
}
```

but `onopen` event on data channel is never executed and channel is in connecting state. The code is working when I open it on the same computer (one in incognito mode) in Chromium.

The Turn and Stun servers I've found on internet. Is there a way to test if they're ok?

I'm testing this code using two computers connected to same router but one is using VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You can test if your network is set-up correctly for a call by using the webRTC-tester:
https://test.webrtc.org/

2.) You can test if the Turn and Stun Server is working by using:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/